# Regex c# obtain subgroup of a captured group

Tags: c#, regex

It seems a simple question, but I don't think it is so easy.

From the example string `AAACARACBBBBBDZAAAAEE`, I want to extract the first 8 characters (= `AAACARAC`) and from this resulting 8-char long string, I want to extract everything except the leading '`A`' characters (= `CARAC`).

I tried with this regex `(?^[A]<WORD>\w{8})`, but I dont know how to apply another regex on the captured group named WORD?

Comment: Why not simply try WORD.TrimStart('A')? RegEx is a nice thing but not a "heal-everything" thingy...

Comment: @horcrux Thanks you for your suggestion, but If I do your suggestion, The result is CARACBBB  (It append the BBB), and I just want CARAC.

Comment: If you want the first 8 character then simply use string method substring.   : string input = "AAACARACBBBBBDZAAAAEE"; string output = input.Substring(0,8);  Then apply Regex.

Comment: If you're using C# you could just do `new string(str.Take(8).SkipWhile(c => c == 'A').ToArray())`

Comment: @LocEngineer Apparently the number of A is important because he wants to match until the 8-th character of the original string, so you cannot trim all the As away.

Comment: I can't use C# function, it must be done within a regular expression , but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @J.Doe _"I can't use C" function, it must be done within a regular expression"_ **Why** is this question tagged "C#" then??

Comment: @J.Doe Then you shouldn't tag this as C#

Comment: I corrected my comment, it is a C# question. @horcux you are right, I need to match until the 8-th character of the original string, that is why I wrote that I think it is not an easy question :)

Comment: The problem wasn't your comment.  The issue is that you do not want a C# answer but you tagged this as C#.

Comment: @juharr Please consider that the regex flavor may vary according to the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you want:

```
(?=^.{8}(.*)$)A*(?<WORD>.*?)\1$
```

See a demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%5e.%7b8%7d%28.*%29%24%29A*%28%3f%3cWORD%3e.*%3f%29%5c1%24&i=AAACARACBBBBBDZAAAAEE&r=) (click then on "Table" for looking at the specific matches).

The regex firs will match the first eight characters looking for what comes next (matching this "tail" in the first capturing group), then will restart from the beginning of the string excluding all the trailing As and matching for as less character as possible such that these characters are followed by the same content of the first capturing group.

Comment: Thank you very much @horcux it is exactly what I needed, you save me several hours of my time. I am gonna understand the regex with the doc, in order to improve my Regex skills. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using C#, you might also use a positive lookbehind to assert 8 chars to the left, matching optional A's and capture the chars that follow in a group.

```
^A*(?<WORD>[^\sA].*)(?<=^.{8})
```

- `^` Start of string
- `A*` match optional repetitions of `A`
- `(?<WORD>` Named group `WORD`

  - `[^\sA].*` Match any non whitespace char except A
- `)` Close named group `WORD`
- `(?<=^.{8})` Assert 8 chars to the left of the current position

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eA*%28%3f%3cWORD%3e%5b%5e%5csA%5d.*%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e.%7b8%7d%29&i=AAACARACBBBBBDZAAAAEE%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m)

[image]

If you only want to match word characters:

```
^A*(?<WORD>[^\WA]\w*)(?<=^\w{8})
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eA*%28%3f%3cWORD%3e%5b%5e%5cWA%5d%5cw*%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cw%7b8%7d%29&i=AAACARACBBBBBDZAAAAEE%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a&o=m)